# Android - how to trigger setOnCheckedChangeListener with linear layout?

Tags: android, checkbox

In my recyclerview onBindView method, I have this piece of code:

```
holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // execute the code inside the onCheckedChanged method
        }
    });
```

And then I also have this:

```
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // do something
                }
            });
```

I'm doing this because I need padding around the checkbox (linear layout), but I need the checkbox to stay the same during scrolling by using `OnCheckedChangedListener`. I need to use the `boolean isChecked` parameter to execute my further code.

How can I execute the code inside the onCheckedChanged by clicking on the linear layout and not on the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the checkbox field on clicking linear layout add this code

```
holder.checkBox.setChecked(!holder.checkBox.isChecked());
```

else add this

```
holder.checkBox.setChecked(holder.checkBox.isChecked());
```

This will call the onCheckedChanged method.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
holder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(holder.checkBox.isChecked()){
               holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
               //do your code for check status false
          }
        else{
             holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
             //do your code for check status true
          }
    }
});
```